# R dplyr summarise one column value based on index of fun(another column)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame as this, and want the output as shown desired at the end. Instead, I get the NA output in the middle. Is there any way to do what I want using dplyr?

```
x <- c(1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678)
y <- c(95138, 30004, 90038, 01294, 15914)
z <- c('2014-01-20', '2014-10-30', '2015-04-12', '2010-2-28', '2015-01-01')
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
df$z <- as.Date(df$z)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(y = y[max(z)])

What I get:
     x  y
1 1234 NA
2 5678 NA

Desired Output:
     x     y 
1 1234 90038
2 5678 15914
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `which.max` to get the numeric index of `max` values that can be used for subsetting the 'y' element.  Using `max` just gives the maximum values of `z`.

```
df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise(y= y[which.max(z)])
#     x     y
#1 1234 90038
#2 5678 15914
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because it provides the output desired.

Comment: @user3949008 You may also do `slice(which.max(z))` in place of `summarise` if you need the whole row

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter` and `max` in `dplyr`.

```
df%>%group_by(x)%>%filter(z==max(z))
```

Comment: But this will also get the `z` column which is not needed according to expected result

Comment: This is very interesting. I falsely thought group_by always needs to be followed by summarise. Is it more efficient to get the z column and then select out through another piped operation? Or, using which.max as above?